# How to correctly extend a class in C++ and writing its header file?

Tags: c++, compilation, header

I've got a third party library named `person.lib` and its header `person.h`. This is my actual project structure and it compiles and runs perfectly.

### Actual Structure:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include "person.h"
using namespace person;
using namespace std;

class Client : public Person 
{
    public:
        Client();   
        void onMessage(const char * const);
    private:
        void gen_random(char*, const int);
};

Client::Client() {
    char str[11];
    gen_random(str, 10);
    this->setName(str);
}

void Client::onMessage(const char * const message) throw(Exception &) 
{
    cout << message << endl;
}

void Client::gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    //THIS FUNCTION GENERATES A RANDOM NAME WITH SPECIFIED LENGTH FOR THE CLIENT
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Person *p = new Client;
        p->sayHello();
    }
    catch(Exception &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to refactor my code by dividing the declaration of my `Client` class from its definition and create `client.h` and `client.cpp`. **PAY ATTENTION**: `sayHello()` and `onMessage(const * char const)` are functions of the *person library*.

### Refactored Structure:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "client.h"
using namespace person;
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        try
        {
            Person *p = new Client;
            p->sayHello();
        }
        catch(Exception &e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"
using namespace person;
using namespace std;

Client::Client() {
    char str[11];
    gen_random(str, 10);
    this->setName(str);
}

void Client::onMessage(const char * const message) throw(Exception &) 
{
    cout << message << endl;
}

void Client::gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    //THIS FUNCTION GENERATES A RANDOM NAME WITH SPECIFIED LENGTH FOR THE CLIENT
}
```

**client.h**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include "person.h"

class Client : public Person 
{
    public:
        Client();   
        void onMessage(const char * const);
    private:
        void gen_random(char*, const int);
};
#endif
```

As you can see, I've simply created a `client.h` in which there's the inclusion of the base class `person.h`, then I've created `client.cpp` in which there's the inclusion of `client.h` and the definitions of its functions. Now, the compilation gives me these errors:

```
error C2504: 'Person': base class undefined     client.h    7   1   Test
error C2440: 'inizialization': unable to convert from 'Client *' to 'person::impl::Person *'   main.cpp 15  1   Test
error C2504: 'Person': base class undefined     client.h    7   1   Test
error C2039: 'setName': is not a member of 'Client'  client.cpp 8   1   Test
error C3861: 'sendMessage': identifier not found    client.cpp  34  1   Test
```

It's a merely cut&copy refactoring but it doesn't work and I really don't understand WHY! What's the solution and why it gives me these errors? Is there something about C++ structure that I'm missing?

Comment: In your refactored header you are including `<person.h>` but in your original code it's `"person.h"` Maybe linker didn't find it?

Comment: @jnovacho It was a trascription error, same error after correction.

Comment: client.h does not use the namespace for person.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a dog-n-bird implementation (ruff ruff, cheep cheep)
cLawyer is defined and implemented in main.cpp, while cPerson and cClient are defined in their own header files, implemented in their own cpp file.
A better approach would store the name of the class. Then, one wouldn't need to overload the speak method - one could simply set the className in each derived copy. But that would have provided in my estimates, a less useful example for you.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "cClient.h"

class cLawyer : public cPerson
{
    public:
        cLawyer() : cPerson() {}
        ~cLawyer() {}
        void talk(char *sayWhat){printf("cLawyer says: '%s'\n", sayWhat);}
};

int main()
{
    cPerson newPerson;
    cClient newClient;
    cLawyer newLawyer;

    newPerson.talk("Hello world!");
    newClient.talk("Hello world!");
    newLawyer.talk("Hello $$$");

    return 0;
}
```

**cPerson.h**

```
#ifndef cPerson_h_
#define cPerson_h_

class cPerson
{
    public:
        cPerson();
        virtual ~cPerson();
        virtual void talk(char *sayWhat);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // cPerson_h_
```

**cPerson.cpp**

```
#include "cPerson.h"
#include <cstdio>
cPerson::cPerson()
{
    //ctor
}

cPerson::~cPerson()
{
    //dtor
}

void cPerson::talk(char *sayWhat)
{
    printf("cPerson says: '%s'\n",sayWhat);
}
```

**cClient.h**

```
#ifndef cClient_h_
#define cClient_h_

#include "cPerson.h"

class cClient : public cPerson
{
    public:
        cClient();
        virtual ~cClient();
        void talk(char *sayWhat);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // cClient_h_
```

**cClient.cpp**

```
#include "cClient.h"
#include <cstdio>

cClient::cClient()
{
    //ctor
}

cClient::~cClient()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**Output**

```
cPerson says: 'Hello world!'
cClient says: 'Hello world!'
cLawyer says: 'Hello $$$'
```

**Suggestions noted above:**

```
//In the cPerson class, a var
  char *m_className;

//In the cPerson::cPerson constructer, set the var
  m_className = "cPerson";

//Re-jig the cPerson::speak method
void cPerson::speak(char *sayWhat)
{
  printf("%s says: '%s'\n", m_className, sayWhat);
}

// EDIT: *** remove the speak methods from the cClient and cLawyer classes ***

//Initialize the clas name apporpriately in derived classes
//cClient::cClient
  m_className = "cClient";


//Initialize the clas name apporpriately in derived classes
//cLaywer::cLaywer
  m_className = "cLawyer";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've modified my code as the first post but it doesn't work anyway, same error! **edit:** I don't have person.cpp. I've got only its header and person.lib

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry you're not able to translate it into a working solution for you. It's fine that you only have the person.lib and person.h files. You don't need the .cpp file if you have the object code it is compiled to.

Comment: I've updated my first post in a clear way, maybe you can see where's the problem! :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I note, that you've not included a `using namespace person` declaration in your client.h file. Perhaps that's it?

Comment: It now compiles!!! But... why? I've declared `using namespace person` in the client.cpp and, as said before in other comments, the `using` instruction is discouraged in header files.

**edit**: it compiles but it doesn't work as expected. It seems that `onMessage()` and `sayHello()` aren't inherited from Person.

Comment: Great. Well, the declaration of Client relies on the declaration of Person. This declaration is needed _before_ the Client class definition can be processed. So, both the .h and the .cpp files need to know about the internals of Person.h. As for `onMessage` and `sayHello` - is the behaviour different now than it was when all code was in a single file? If you wish to inherit these functions from Person, dont redeclare them as functions in Client. Doing so means that these members of Person will be replaced by the inherited-class specific ones. I'll update the notes in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38341/discussion-between-angelo-and-enhzflep)

Comment: While your example is programmatically sound, it is logically incorrect: Lawyers aren't people.

Answer (score 6):

You are declaring the class Client twice - once in the `.h` file and once in `.cpp`. You only need to declare it in the `.h` file.
<strike>You also need to put the `using namespace person;` to the `.h` file.</strike>
If class Person is in namcespace person, use the `person::Person` to access it.

The `client.cpp` must contain definitions only!

I think for the linker the class Client defined in client.h and class Client defined in client.cpp are different classes, thus it cannot find the implementation of Client::Client(). I purpose to remove the declaration of class Client from the client.cpp and leave there only definitions of functions:

```
// client.cpp

#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include "client.h"
using namespace std;

Client::Client()
{
    //DO STUFF
}

void Client::onMessage(const char * const message)
{
    //DO STUFF
}


void Client::gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: `using namespace` should be avoided in headers.

Comment: look edited code, if I put `using namespace person` in client.h I've got `Error 2 error LNK2019: reference to extern symbol "public: __thiscall Client::Client(void)" (??0Client@@QAE@XZ) not resolved in function _WinMain@16`

Comment: class Person is in namespace `person::impl::Person`

Comment: did you meant `client.cpp`?

Comment: But why definition only? I'm looking at C++ primer and a class it's written like I've done, with functions' definitions inside the class. How I should correct my code?

Comment: @Angelo it is your choice: if the member functions are defined inside the class definition, they are implicitly `inline`. The drawback is that the client code has compile time dependency on all the member definitions. If you separate them out into a `.cpp` file, then the client code only has a link-time dependency.

Comment: @juanchopanza So it's not true that, in this case, client.cpp **must** contain definitions only!

Comment: @Angelo it is kind of true: it should not have any declarations.